# Send parameter details to remote URL and get results in xml xcode

Tags: xcode

I am doing a Flight booking app. The user will enter the details like 
FROM CITY and DESTINATION CITY details, along with departure date, passenger information like no of adults and no of children fields. One the use clicks the Search button, the app needs to send the details to a remote url and do an INNER JOIN of two tables 
airport master and City will return the available flights details in 
XML format.

In my past experience, I have only created sqlite table locally and 
have copied it to my app folder and manipulated to populate a table 
view. This is a very new process for me and I am kind of struck 
having searched the net and many books with no proper leads.

My request is how to send the user entered details to a remote 
url, where should I write the query with inner join(the data is 
stored in a remote sqlite for which we will send the url request) and 
get the result in xml format.
 Any examples or tutorial would really be of great help. Thanking you 
in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the userdetails in the url like @"www.abcd.com/user.php?usename=userna&password=pw". You have to write the php file in the server.In that php file you have to connect to database and check whether the user existing or not.